# Grunt - Is it possible to pass global custom functions to external tasks which were loaded by grunt.loadTasks?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, task

I have custom functions that work well when the tasks are defined in the same gruntfile.js but my gruntfile.js now has more than 2000 lines and its becoming hard to maintain. Is it possible to use the functions globally without having to define them again in each task file?. When they are called from the external task neither of the two functions work. I just get error function not defined.

I have next structure

```
gruntfile.js

grunt/tasks/functions.js

grunt/tasks/styles.js
```

The content of the files is as follows:

**gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt)

    function globalFunctionOne(param1) {
       console.log('yay it works from main file');
    }

    grunt.initConfig({});

    console.log(grunt.config());

    grunt.loadTasks('grunt/tasks')

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dist'];
}
```

**functions.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    function globalFunctionTwo(param1) {
        console.log('yay it works from partial file');
    }
}
```

***styles.js***

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config('sass', {
        options: {
            implementation: sass,
            includePaths: globalFunctionOne('dev'),
            outputStyle: 'expanded',
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                globalFunctionTwo('dist'),
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2,000 lines?  That's a long gruntfile.  Here's a gruntfile you can adopt to break apart your code into something more modular:

**gruntfile.js**

```
function init(grunt) {
    "use strict";
    function loadConfig(pattern) {
        let config = {},
            fileName,
            fileData;

        grunt.file.expand(pattern).forEach(function (filePath) {
            fileName = filePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
            fileData = require('./' + filePath)(grunt);
            config[fileName] = fileData;
        });

        return config;
    }

    function loadGrunt() {
        const config = {
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
        };

        require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

        if (grunt.file.exists('grunt/tasks')) {
            grunt.log.writeln('task directory found, loading tasks...');
            grunt.loadTasks('grunt/tasks');
        }

        grunt.util._.extend(config, loadConfig('grunt/configs/**/*.js'));

        grunt.initConfig(config);
    }
    loadGrunt();

}

module.exports = init;
```

What this gruntfile does:

- It dynamically creates a config object for grunt to use by loading
  every `.js` file it finds in `project-root/grunt/configs`.  The name
  of each file corresponds to its key for the grunt config object.
- It dynamically loads any tasks from `project-root/grunt/tasks`

If your config uses `grunt-contrib-copy`, then in your project, you'd have a config file resembling the following:

**project-root/grunt/configs/copy.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        base: {
            options: {
                process: function (content) {
                    return grunt.template.process(content);
                }
            },
            src: 'grunt/templates/base.url.js',
            dest: 'www/source/config/base.url.js'
        },
        pluginManifest: {
            src: 'cordova/template/package.json',
            dest: '<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/package.json'
        },
        splashScreens: {
            expand: true,
            cwd:"grunt/templates/",
            src: "screen/**",
            dest: '<%= create.dest %>/res/'
        }
    };
};
```

You can then shift your global functions to a `helpers` javascript file and import them into the configs in typical Node.js fashion:

**project-root/grunt/configs/sass.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  const helpers = require("../helpers.js)(grunt);
  return {
    options: {
      implementation: sass,
      includePaths: helpers.globalFunctionOne('dev'),
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      sourceMap: true
    },
    dist: {
      files: {
        globalFunctionTwo('dist'),
      }
    }
  };
};
```

**project-root/grunt/helpers.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  function globalFunctionOne(param1) {
    console.log('yay it works from main file');
  }

  function globalFunctionTwo(param1) {
    console.log('yay it works from partial file');
  }

  return {
    globalFunctionOne,
    globalFunctionTwo
  }; 
};
```